# find nearest point to a fitting line and the neighborhood of it in Matlab

Tags: matlab, date-range

Supposed I have two random double array, which  means that one `x` coordinate might have multiple `y` value.

```
X = randi([-10 10],1,1000); 
Y = randi([-10 10],1,1000);
```

Then I give a line equation: `y=ax+b`.

I want to find the nearest point to the nearest point to the line based on every `x` point. And when I find this point, I will find it's neighborhood points within specific range. Please forgive my poor English, maybe following picture can help more.

Because I have a lot of data points, I hope there is an efficient way to deal with this problem.

[image: image explanation]

Comment: Do you want to first project the points to the line? Based on your drawing you have not done that.

Comment: No, I don't want to project it.
I only want to find where is the nearest point to the line at each x coordinate and then give it a range to find its neighborhood

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if your X's are discrete you can try something like:

```
xrng = [-10 10];
yrng = [-10 10];
a = rand;
b = rand;
f = @(x) a*x + b;
X = randi(xrng,1,1000);
Y = randi(yrng,1,1000);
ezplot(f,xrng);
hold on;
plot(X,Y,'.');
xx = xrng(1):xrng(2);
nbrSz = 2;
nx = diff(xrng);
nearestIdx = zeros(nx,1);
nbrIdxs = cell(nx,1);
for ii = 1:nx
    x = xx(ii);
    y = f(x);
    idx = find(X == x);
    [~,idxidx] = min(abs(y - Y(idx)));
    nearestIdx(ii) = idx(idxidx);
    nbrIdxIdxs = abs(Y(nearestIdx(ii)) - Y(idx)) <= nbrSz;
    nbrIdxs{ii} = idx(nbrIdxIdxs);
    plot(X(nearestIdx(ii)),Y(nearestIdx(ii)),'og');
    plot(X(nearestIdx(ii)) + [0 0],Y(nearestIdx(ii)) + [-nbrSz nbrSz],'g')
    plot(X(nbrIdxs{ii}),Y(nbrIdxs{ii}),'sy')
end
```

Comment: This code looks great! I have one more question. In this code, I found every point within the range nbrSz. Can I add step condition into the range? 
For example, if  nbrSz=4 and step=2, I only want to find out neighborhood points under distance 2 and 4.

Comment: sure, just do:
nbrIdxIdxs = (abs(Y(nearestIdx(ii)) - Y(idx)) <= nbrSz) & (abs(Y(nearestIdx(ii)) - Y(idx)) >= step);
and please accept my answer if it helped you :)

Comment: I mean only the exact distance: 4 and 2, not from 2 to 4. And because the condition could be [1:10:2], which means only pitch distance 1,3,5,7,9, is there a way not to write several (  )&(  )&(  ) ?

Comment: if the required distances are evenly spaced (odd numbers for example), you can use the rem( . , . ) function. and in this case: rem( abs(...), 2) == 1;

Comment: but if I use rem( abs(...), 2) == 1, it will choose every odd numbers. But it didn't apply the distance constraint on it. I will get distance between nearest point of 1, 3, 5, 7,9, 11......until the farest.  
And I not only want odd or even numbers, the step might be 3 or 4 or anything. What do you suggest in this case?

Comment: you can create a vector of allowed distances, for example: `aDist = 1:step:maxDist;` and then use `ismember` function like so: `ismember( abs(...), aDist)`